# On the compactness theorem

Tags: logic, topology

I have seen compactness theorem in logic many a times but I heard of compactness theorem in topology, I don't know what does it mean in topology but I see that it has to do something with open covers. My query is can we use compactness theorem in topology to prove the existence of ordered and non Archimedean field. It can be done using compactness theorem in logic but I was wondering if it's also true for topological compactness.

Comment: I believe you will have a much better experience if you post this question on https://math.stackexchange.com/
This site is more geared toward specific questions about computer programming.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Archimedean fields, but a topological space is *compact* if every open cover has a finite subcover. Tychonoff's theorem says that the product of compact spaces is compact (w.r.t. the product topology). Apparently, one can use it to prove the compactness theorem in propositional logic.
In computability theory, there is also a compactness theorem for Cantor space (the infinite 0-1-sequences with a certain topology), see Soare's *Turing Computability*, Chapter 8. It includes König's Lemma, which is also employed in some proofs of the compactness theorem in propositional logic, so they should be analogous.